# Unexplained code generation for global register variables on mingw-w64

Tags: c, gcc, mingw-w64

In our project we make use of global register variables.  In particular, we use **%r12**, **%r13**, **%r14** for 64-bit and **%esi**, **%edi** for 32-bit code.

For example:

```
register void * my_var asm ("r12");
```

These global vars are accessed from different modules (.c files).
According to the ABI (http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf), these regs “belong” to the calling function, and the called function is required to preserve their values.

For mingw64, we can see these regs are saved on the stack before any call are made, even if that call doesn't use these regs inside. However, this doesn't occur when we compile using gcc on linux.  Has anyone run into this or understand why this may be?

```
pushq %r14
pushq %r13
pushq %r12
pushq %rbx
subq $40, %rsp
movq %rcx, %rbx
xorl %ecx, %ecx
call my_func
testl %eax, %eax
je .L40
movq 168(%rbx), %rax
addq $40, %rsp
popq %rbx
popq %r12
popq %r13
popq %r14
ret
```

Comment: What versions of gcc are you using (both the one that saves the registers and the one that doesn't)?  Have you experimented with `-ffixed-r12`?  And (I gotta ask) what are you doing where starving the compiler out of registers yields a benefit?

Comment: Hi David, this is for a bytecode interpreter where the virtual pc and stack pointer must (a the very least) be in registers after a dispatch.  The compiler can't *see* this and I wouldn't expect it to.  The performance benefit is considerable.
We have experimented with the `-fixed-<reg>` solution, but we remain uncomfortable because we don't understand why other platforms don't require this workaround.
Versions:
- mingw-w64: gcc (x86_64-posix-sjlj-rev1) 4.9.0
- mingw32: gcc (GCC) 4.8.1
- Linux 64-bit: gcc (Ubuntu 4.9.1-16ubuntu6) 4.9.1

Comment: Ahh, an interpreter. Ok then. So, it works correctly in 4.9.1, but not 4.9.0 or earlier?  Well, that seems like a place start.  Either an older version on linux (to see if it breaks) or a newer version of mingw-w64.